# How To Activate A Table's Sort Feature With VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing in VBA and plan to set some values in a table, and then for convenience have the VBA choose a specific column and sort like you could with a mouse. Is there any way to activate the cell that contains that specific header and sort the table?

Comment: Turn on the macro recorder while you perform the action(s) you want to automate, then use the generated code as a starting point

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'activate' do you mean 'select' or are you trying to filter the table?

---

**Answer:**
You can filter the table like this...

```
Sub name()
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$50").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<your criteria>", _
Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<more criteria>"
End Sub
```

Where `Range("$A$1:$C$50")` is your table range, `Field:=5` is the column number you want to filter on (e.g. 2 for column B, 5 for column E, etc), and `Criteria1` is what you want to filter on. You can use `xlAnd` or `xlOr` for the `Operator`.

Comment: I will edit my original comment (formatting is hard).